# NodeJS crypto and jsSHA different results for SHA-1

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I have to port some browser code which uses jsSHA to NodeJS and I was expecting to use the crypto module, but for some reason, this two pieces of code generate different results when, I believe, they should be the same:

```
let s1 = crypto.createHmac('sha1', '1234').update('4321').digest('base64');

var hmacObj = new jsSHA("SHA-1", "TEXT");
hmacObj.setHMACKey('1234', "B64")
hmacObj.update('4321')
let s2 = hmacObj.getHMAC("B64");

console.log(`${s1} <===> ${s2}`);
// EL8JVAKqxIzgv0ELy/9zDxzlKIc= <===> RvRFQNm8hvN+vwvp8zNxs/z6P2s=
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You told jsSHA that the key was base64. You didn't tell Node that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the same result as your jsSHA code:

```
crypto.createHmac('sha1', new Buffer('1234', 'base64'))
      .update('4321')
      .digest('base64')
```